# Clicking all elements on the page with Xpath causes an ElementNotVisibileException

Tags: python, selenium

I've got a helper function to look through the page and open every help button it finds. It's nice and simple;

```
def openHelp(ff):
    """
    Opens all the help buttons on the screen
    @type ff: instance of webdriver
    @param ff: firefox instance of webdriver
    """
    allHelpButtons = ff.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="helpButton"]')
    for helpButton in allHelpButtons:
        helpButton.click()
```

However on some pages the helpbuttons may be hidden along with their corresponding fields by javascript which appears to be what is causing an `ElementNotVisibileException` when Selenium tries to click those hidden buttons.

Every help button appears the same in the markup, there isn't a `display:none` applied so I can't check like that. They appear as such;

```
<a class="helpButton" title="Help about: Field" href="#">
    <img alt="Help about: Field" src="/static/images/helpIcon.png">
</a>
```

If this exception exists I assume there must be a method you can use to check if an element is visible. Ideally I'd like to only collect all visible elements in to my `allHelpButtons` list, but I can't find any docs on this.
Can I perform a check with my xpath search or do I have to do a check on the elements once they've been collected?

*bonus question*

I was also wondering, if you can select a list item by matching the name and the value. For example I have a Yes/No radio button selection defined in the page as a `ul`;

```
<ul class="compact horizontal ">
    <li>
        <input id="id_fieldname_0_true" type="radio" value="True" name="fieldname">
        <label for="id_fieldname_0_true">Yes</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="id_fieldname_0_false" type="radio" value="False" name="fieldname">
        <label for="id_fieldname_0_false">No</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Obviously the id is unique but I'd rather be able to use a selector to pick out the 'name' and the 'value' because I think that'll make it easier to make generic selectors which I can pass values to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `is_displayed` function.

Check the source code below, line 162:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py

As for your bonus question, this is done by XPath too, to click the Yes button radio:

```
//label[text()='Yes']/preceding-sibling::input
```

and for No:

```
//label[text()='No']/preceding-sibling::input
```